# INSERT values into a table taken from a table and another which is referenced by date function

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I want to insert into a database some new values, while also inserting another values from other table which primary key is the date. Thing is I want to get the element which primary key is the value of `CURRENT_DATE`. Something like:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table
   SELECT
       some_table.name 
       some_table.email
       date_indexed_table.id as "begin"   -- this should be 1 month before ID
       date_indexed_table.id as "end" -- this should be 1 month today ID
   FROM some_table
        JOIN date_indexed_table ON date_indexed_table.date_id = (CURRENT_DATE)::date;
```

dest_table should look like:

| name | email | begin | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stewie | stewie@gmail.com | 2 | 1 |

Where "2" and "1" are the id associated to the primary keys "11/01/2022" and "11/12/2021" (which are of "date" type), but im having trouble doing this insert.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `(CURRENT_DATE)::date` can be simplified to `CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: Why do you expect begin and end to be different? They are both date_indexed_table.id so they'll be the same.

Comment: I need to have two different ids (which belong in the same column) in a single row, how can I reference both at the same time without repeating date_indexed_table.id?

Comment: Please post the actual table definition (ddl), some sample data and expected results you are after, all as text - **no images**.   What you claim you need  *to have two different ids (which belong in the same column) in a single row* simply **cannot happen** if you have a scalar defined column.